# Search for a Facebook page with url using page name and location

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have Google Map where user is searching for location after location results I have location name, lat, long, address.

I have to check if there is page existing on Facebook having that name and lat, long and address then I need to get the Facebook URL of that page to show user.

Comment: what did you try so far? please hit the official docs and do some research and testing first, this is a platform for developers and you are required to try to solve stuff on your own first.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching/

Hit the `/pages/search?q={your-query}` endpoint and then create some logic to determine if that is enough of a match for you. If it's a match then take the `link` field and return that. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: I used this but facebook is not approving my app for "Public page content access".

Comment: Is there any other way to find the facebook page url from name, lat,long and address?

Comment: Not that I know of